# Using OpenTelemetry, how we can inject trace details automatically to application logs written in Nodejs / Go

Tags: node.js, go, jaeger, distributed-tracing, open-telemetry

In python, there is an **option to inject trace details(tracid,spanid) to application logs** using environment variable (export OTEL_PYTHON_LOG_CORRELATION=true). **Is there something similar in Nodejs or Go**.
I couldn't find any autoinstrumentaion for tracing in Go (We can manually instrument, by creating spans and wrappers for handlers). So I don't expect answer from Go language, but probably, Node might have a solution

Comment: In Go, You can do this using context. Refer [here](https://golang.org/pkg/context/) and look in to tracing tool [zipkin](https://zipkin.io/pages/tracers_instrumentation#:~:text=Tracing%20information%20is%20collected%20on,the%20data%20together%20into%20spans.)

Comment: that is possible with context,, so that we need to add span,, and wrappers around handler function.. that is why I said, manually it is possible,, but in python,, you don't need such king of wrappers. you only need to import opentelemetry library, and configure backend like jaeger

Comment: I received a solution in Nodejs from the opentelemetry  official support community . plz find the answer here -->https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-js-api/discussions/67.  Solution is to use log framework like bunyan, pino, winston